# Proper Partition Alignment

Tags: raid, partition, storage-area-network, diskpart

I'm trying to follow the advice from [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) about partition alignment. Our San is an EMC, the disks are in a 4 disk raid 10. This services an I/O intensive application, 60:40 write:read.

According to the `wmic` query in the article for `Partition_Offset`, I get 1048576.

According to my SAN administrator the `Stripe_Unit_Size` is 524288000. Does that even sound right?

The simple calculation to find if you're aligned or not is:

`Partition_Offset ÷ Stripe_Unit_Size`
`1048576 / 524288000 = .002`

This is not an integer, so it appears we are not aligned.

Using `diskpart` to reformat the drives, what `Partition_Offset` and `File_Allocation_Unit` should we use?

Comment: What version of Windows? Recent ones just sort this all out for you automatically

Comment: [Disk Partition Alignment - from Jimmy May](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmymay/archive/2009/05/08/disk-partition-alignment-sector-alignment-make-the-case-with-this-template.aspx) and [this article from mssqltips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2119/partition-offset-and-allocation-unit-size-of-a-disk-for-sql-server/) will help you.